# Need help! Rails ActiveRecord not finding primary key (ID) in find_each

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have some code that magically stopped working (no code was pushed)!

I have a function that gets called on a nightly basis to charge some subscriptions. The function called is this:

```
def cycle_subscriptions( async = true )
  Subscriptions::Subscription.ready_to_cycle.find_each do |s|
    if async
      CycleSubscriptionBillingPeriodWorker.perform_async( s.id )
    else
      s.cycle_billing_period!
    end
  end
end
```

`ready_to_charge` creates some scopes via this:

```
scope :cycleable, ->{ where.not(status: [self.statuses[:suspended], self.statuses[:suspended_payment_failed], self.statuses[:cancelled], self.statuses[:cancelled_payment_failed], self.statuses[:trial_expired]]) }

scope :ready_to_cycle, ->{ cycleable.where( "next_bill_date < ?", Time.now ) }
```

This locally creates a query like this:

```
SELECT  "subscriptions_subscriptions".* FROM "subscriptions_subscriptions" WHERE ("subscriptions_subscriptions"."status" NOT IN (1, 5, 2, 8, 7)) AND (next_bill_date < '2023-01-13 16:40:05.365004')  ORDER BY "subscriptions_subscriptions"."id" ASC LIMIT 1000
```

However, on the server, it creates this query:

```
SELECT  "subscriptions_subscriptions".* FROM "subscriptions_subscriptions" WHERE ("subscriptions_subscriptions"."status" NOT IN (1, 5, 2, 8, 7)) AND (next_bill_date < '2023-01-13 16:59:49.014069')  ORDER BY "subscriptions_subscriptions"."" ASC LIMIT 1000
```

Notice the absence of the `id` in `ORDER BY "subscriptions_subscriptions"."" ASC`. I believe the `find_each` is what is appending that clause.

Why would it not be adding the primary key field into that query?? I'm lost and happy to share any info I can that might help solve this.

Answer (score 1):

ANSWER: Well, it seems that somehow, someone deleted the pkey and index for the id column (not the column itself) from the db. I ran `ALTER TABLE collections ADD PRIMARY KEY (id)` and got everything back operational. Looks like I got people to talk to now - not sure how that even happened.